# Replace numbers dynamically which exist next to a certain word or certain characters? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to be able to replace numbers before a certain characters dynamically?

In the example below I'd want to target the numbers next to `kW` - The reason why I'm wanting to replace is that the values aren't generated by myself, I'm grabbing a list of products from a database which I don't control as I would of done exactly @Winter has mentioned.

Original:

```
Torch 90kW
Toy Car 340kW
Battery 120kW
Electric Toothbrush 5kW
```

Replace to:

```
Torch 10kW
Toy Car 90kW
Battery 40kW
Electric Toothbrush 15kW
```

What currently have, the only reason why I don't want to use this:

```js
/*  Only reason why i'm not wanting to use this is because if there was digit before hand then they'll  get replace aswell. 

As you can see below the 200 and 30 would get replaced. */

let stringToReplace = '200 Toy 30Kw';
stringToReplace = stringToReplace.replace(/\d+/g, "20");

document.write(stringToReplace);
```

Comment: what does not work? what have you tried? what is the rule for changing the number?

Comment: Can you provide us with [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried? We can help you fix your code. But will not create code for you without your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and some regex:

```
"Electric Toothbrush 15kW".replace(/\d+(?=kW)/, "999");
// Electric Toothbrush 999kW
```

This method can also accept a callback function:

```
"Electric Toothbrush 15kW".replace(/\d+(?=kW)/, match => Number(match) * 10);
// Electric Toothbrush 150kW
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to select the digits followed by the `kW`. And replace it to your desired value

```js
const testCases = [`Torch 90kW`, `Toy Car 340kW`, `Battery 120kW`, `Electric Toothbrush 5kW`];
const testNums = [10, 90, 40, 15];

const regex = /\d+kW/;

console.log(testCases.map((a, i) => a.replace(regex, `${testNums[i]}kw`)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use template literals for all these.

Example:

```js
let torchNumber = 40; 
// 40 would be your dynamic number
let torchString = `Torch ${torchNumber}kW`
//Your dynamic code should be inside ${}
console.log(torchString)
```